# Flutter-Firebase how to push Future<FirebaseUser> to another class

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create Authentication forms.
The user can register with e-mail and password. After eMailandPassword registration is completed successfully, the user is redirected to Verification page. I need user's info so that I can register his phone number to the firebase.
Here is my createUser function;

```
    void createUser() async {
        dynamic result = await _auth.createNewUser(
            _nameController.text, _emailContoller.text, _passwordController.text);
        if (result == null) {
          print('Email is not valid');
        } else {
          print(result.toString());
          _nameController.clear();
          _passwordController.clear();
          _emailContoller.clear();
    
          Future<FirebaseUser> user = _auth.getCurrentUser();
**/////HOW TO PASS user to the PhoneVerification class. ??**

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhoneVerification(user:user)),
          );
        }
      }
```

If I pass as Future user, I cannot access its value in PhoneVerification class.

```
class PhoneVerification extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseUser> user;
  const PhoneVerification({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhoneVerificationState createState() => _PhoneVerificationState();
}
```

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: Where are you trying to access the user's value in the `PhoneVerification` class?

Comment: why do you need Future? just do await and use FirebaseUser as the type

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you think I don't need User's value while phone verification?

Answer (score 1):

```
void createUser() async {
    dynamic result = await _auth.createNewUser(
        _nameController.text, _emailContoller.text, _passwordController.text);
    if (result == null) {
      print('Email is not valid');
    } else {
      print(result.toString());
      _nameController.clear();
      _passwordController.clear();
      _emailContoller.clear();

      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.getCurrentUser();

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhoneVerification(user:user)),
      );
    }
  }

class PhoneVerification extends StatefulWidget {
 final FirebaseUser user;
 const PhoneVerification({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _PhoneVerificationState createState() => _PhoneVerificationState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  void createUser() async {
        dynamic result = await _auth.createNewUser(
            _nameController.text, _emailContoller.text, _passwordController.text);
        if (result == null) {
          print('Email is not valid');
        } else {
          print(result.toString());
          _nameController.clear();
          _passwordController.clear();
          _emailContoller.clear();
    
          FirebaseUser user = await _auth.getCurrentUser();//<=== await here


          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhoneVerification(user:user)),
          );
        }
      }
```

But as Frank mentioned, are you sure you want to be passing a `FirebaseUser` object to your other class? The documentation explains well how to manage phone auth.

Comment: Do you think I don't need User's value while phone verification?  I thought I need it